# Синхронизация доступа к pipe посредством сигналов

Tags: linux, c, unix, ipc

Два процесса с общим родителем должны обменяться пидами посредством одного канала pipe.
Мой код:

```
int pipes[2];
pipe(pipes);
FILE *out = fdopen(pipes[1], "w");
FILE *in = fdopen(pipes[0], "r");
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
setvbuf(out, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
sigset_t *set = malloc(sizeof(sigset_t));
sigemptyset(set);
sigaddset(set, SIGUSR1);
pid_t first = fork();
if (!first) {
    pid_t brot;
    fprintf(out, "%d\n", getpid());
    sigwait(set, NULL);
    fscanf(in, "%d", &brot);
    printf("Second PID = %d\n", brot);
    exit(0);
}
pid_t second = fork();
if (!second) {
    pid_t brot;
    fscanf(in, "%d", &brot);
    kill(brot, SIGUSR1);
    fprintf(out, "%d\n", getpid());
    printf("First PID = %d\n", brot);
    exit(0);
}
```

Потом в родителе закрываю все дескрипторы и завершаю программу.
При выводе появляется лишь строчка "First PId = x", где х - значение. Почему не выводится вторая строчка?Складывается ощущение, что первый сын не получает сигнал от килл, но почему - непонятно. Вроде бы посылаться сигнал должен гарантированно после того, как первый процесс попадет в режим ожидания. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, проблема в том, что вы обработчик сигнала `SIGUSR1` (надо вызвать `sigaction()` или `signal()`) не установили. Вот процесс first и умирает...

А также `sigwait(set, NULL);` у вас не должен нормально компилироваться, задайте во втором аргументе адрес переменой.

Comment: Спасибо большое, правки решили проблему

Comment: Я вчера, кстати, [копался](http://dpaste.com/010XBYN) в этом — подвесил `SIGUSR1` на `SIG_IGN` и у меня `first` [зависал](http://dpaste.com/35VC4WD) в `sigwait`... есть идеи, почему?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, темная это история, [вот тут](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2009-October/057340.html) тоже человек пытался разобраться. Наверное kernel копать надо, но не факт, что прозрачную идею, стоящую за таким поведением удастся нарыть....